# How to formally represent the optimal solution to this problem $\min {\sum_c {n_c^2}}\;s.t.\sum_c{n_c}=n$

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

The objective is
$$\mathop {\min }\limits_{{n_c} \in N} \sum\limits_{c = 1}^C {n_c^2}\\
s.t.\sum\limits_{c = 1}^C {{n_c}}  = n
$$
where $N$ is non-negative integer.

I guess the optimal solution is $n_c=\frac{n}{C}$ for each $c$. However, it is possible $C$ is not divisible by $n$.

So, I have two problems:

1. how to formally represent the optimal solution to this problem?
2. how to prove the solution is optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  For the continuous problem, you can invoke properties of convex minimization problems or just show directly that any other feasible solution can be improved.  Suppose $n_i \not= n_j$ for some $i,j$.  Then show that 
$$n_i^2+n_j^2 > \left(\frac{n_i+n_j}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{n_i+n_j}{2}\right)^2.$$

A similar argument applies to the integer case, for which every optimal solution satisfies $n_c\in\{\lfloor n/C\rfloor,\lceil n/C\rceil\}$ for all $c$.  To determine the number $L$ of values that should be at their lower bounds, solve
$$L \lfloor n/C\rfloor + (C-L)\lceil n/C\rceil = n$$
for $L$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I am looking for! BTW, is there a typo in formulation for solving $L$? it seems $L \lfloor n/C\rfloor + (C-L)\lceil n/C\rceil = n$.

Comment: Yes, corrected.